# First time to try water simulation but I can't do it

Tags: fluid-simulation

I used HDRI image to light my scene. I was just trying to learn how to simulate fluid. In the viewport, the fluid is in good shape:

[image]

But it renders the domain in the final image instead of rendering the particles, even after baking the simulation! how can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the newly updated fluid simulation (Mantaflow) you need to enable ‘Mesh’ in the settings. This uses the fluid particles (that you can see in your screenshot) into the final mesh. You may need to re-bake the simulation to see the result (there are some known issues with Replay cache mode not always auto-detecting that the simulation has changed and needs rebaking - try changing the Resolution or change the cache to Final to allow it to be baked).